# Content Query Web Part on a multilingual SP site

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, content-query-web-part, publishing-page

I have a SP 2010 installation, installed in English. I have some sub sites that use publishing, for news and such. On my home page I have a CQWP that shows the news nicely formatted. 
The CQWP has the following in "Query".

- Show items from the following list: (A publishing site's pages)
- Show items of this content type group: (Page Layout Content Type)
- Show items of this content type: (Article Page)

I later installed a Danish language pack and switched my language to danish. Funny thing happens. All the publishing content vanished.

When i went back to the web part, i noticed in the query, that the "Show items of this content type group:" is set to "all content types" but no content is showing. If i select the Article page content type and hit save, the content shows up again, but if I again switch display language, the content disappears again and i have to do the same routine over again.

What am i missing here ?

How can i have the CQWP show content regardless of the selected language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have unofficially gotten confirmation from Microsoft support that this is a bug in SharePoint.

Here are the steps to reproduce the error.

1. Set Windows Language to en-us.
2. SharePoint site should be in another language then English. (I use Danish)
3. Install English language pack to SharePoint.
4. Set publishing subsite to use English as alternative language.
5. Add a CQWP to the front page to display content from the subsites pages.

To fix the issue, I removed the Alternate language setting in the language setting for the publishing subsite.
OR. 
Remove English language as system language and choose, in my case, Faroese and the error will not be there.